# Append text with variables Objective C

Tags: objective-c, string, nsstring, append

I was trying to append text without any success until I tryied this:

```
NSString *n_result = @"";
n_result = [n_result stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"The number "]];
    n_result = [n_result stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ", n_analyze]];
    n_result = [n_result stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@", has "]];
    n_result = [n_result stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i ", steps]];
    n_result = [n_result stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"steps to reach 1"]];
```

The thing is, there must be a simpler way of doing this. But I don't know how.
Can anyone help me with this? I have been searching everywhere how to do this "better".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[NSString stringWithFormat:@"The number %@ , has %i steps to reach 1", n_analyze, steps]`

Comment: Works like a charm thank you very much. I used it like this if anyone wants to know NSString *n_result = @""; n_result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"The number %@ , has %i steps to reach 1", n_analyze, steps];

Comment: @LucianoOliveira There is no need to assign `@""` first. Just do: `NSString *n_result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"The number %@ , has %i steps to reach 1", n_analyze, steps];`

Comment: @LucianoOliveira In projects with excessive string formatting (all my projects), I declare SS() macro to shorten that syntax. `#define SS(fmt,...) [NSString stringWithFormat:fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__]` in `.pch`-file. Now it becomes `SS(@"Hi, %@!", username)`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a slightly easier way. Use an instance of [`NSMutableString`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableString_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

```
NSMutableString *mutableString = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"The number "];
[mutableString appendFormat:@"%@ ", n_analyze];

// etc..
```